# How to set cursor hand/pointer to JCheckbox?

Tags: java, jcheckbox

Is there a way to set cursor (hand/pointer) to JCheckbox while mouse is over it (hover)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set it by `setCursor` method. Example:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class sample20 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JPanel wnd = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("label");
        checkbox.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // this is what you need
        wnd.add(checkbox);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(wnd);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for the setCursor() method. Don't forget that the class name should start with an upper case character.